# SSIS stuck in validation when running package (SQL Server 2016)

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I've got a very basic SSIS package with a task in it that has a simple Dataflow in it. Source is a table in a database in one SQL Server instance and destination is an identical table in a different instances database. I've done this kind of thing tons of times, but this time, I'm getting a weird occurance.

When I run the package, it freezes on the validation of the destination after 50% has been reached. I've turned off referential integrity for the table, and i'm doing a fast load keeping identity fields and nulls, with table lock and check contraints ticked. The table only contains about 200,000 records and should be fast to copy.

Anyone know what could be causing this?

[image: Log file]
As an extra bit of information, If I execute the task directly it runs fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that was very odd. It turns out that the previous Task (an Execute SQL) was messing things up. I was turning off referential integrity for the table, which should not have adversely affected the dataflow. Removing this sorted out the problem. To be honest I don't need it in this case, it was just copied from a previous package that did need it.

Weird.